# Solving a recurrence relation of conditional probability functions

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

> Suppose you have the recurrence relation for a probability function Q:
>   $$Q(n_1,n_2|n) = Q(n_1-1,n_2|n-1)\frac{n_1-1}{n-1} + Q(n_1,n_2-1|n-1)\frac{n_2-1}{n-1}$$
>   where $n = n_1 + n_2$ and the initial conditions $Q(1,1|2) = 1$, $Q(0,1|1) = Q(1,0|1) = 0$. Show that this satisfies the equation:
>   $$Q(n_1,n_2|n) = \frac{1}{n-1}$$

So my first thought was to use matrix algebra to decompose the problem into the form $Au_n=u_{n+1}$ (similar to what you can do with the fibonacci series with the matrix:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \:\:\:\:\:\:\: u^T = [1,0] $$

(Find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors and then solving for the coefficients will reveal an equation for the n'th fibonacci number, for example, see [here](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~anstee/math223/223fibonacci.pdf))

So... I'd like to do that for this problem, but I don't think that's possible since there isn't as straightforward (linear?) dependence like the fibonacci series.

I can easily see how you could calculate any given $Q(n_1,n_2|n)$ with recursion--and I've also completed a few calculations that agree with the solution give. However taking that last leap of logic to the last step is confusing me.

Any help would be great!

Comment: It would have made sense to link to [the context](http://web.eve.ucdavis.edu/pbg298/pdfs/Genetics_1983-Tajima.pdf) in which you encountered this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation

$$
Q(n_1,n_2\mid n) = \frac{1}{n-1}
$$

holds for $1\le n_i\le n-1$.

Place a black ball between two white balls. In each step, insert a new white ball uniformly at random into one of the gaps between the existing balls. With $n$ the total number of white balls and $n_1$, $n_2$ the numbers of white balls to either side of the black ball, this process is described by your recurrence. The process produces a uniformly random permutation of the $n-1$ balls between the two outermost balls, so the rank of the black ball among these $n-1$ balls is uniformly random, and hence so are $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Alternatively, your equation can readily be proved by induction.

Comment: I can see the proof by induction when keeping one of the $n_i$'s = 1. This trivially gives $$Q(n-1,1) = Q(1,n-1) = \prod_{i=2}^{n-1}{\frac{n-1}{n}} = \frac{1}{n-1}$$ however I can't figure out how to extend this to the $n_i \ne 1$ case

Comment: @lstbl: Both $Q$ terms on the right-hand side of the recurrence are $n-2$ by the induction hypothesis. Since $n_1-1+n_2-1=n-2$, the factors of $n-2$ cancel and you're left with $1/(n-1)$.

Comment: I get it when you assume that the $Q$ terms are always $\frac{1}{n1+n2-1}$, but I'm confused about how you can infer that this is always the case for any $n1$ and $n2$

Comment: @lstbl: They're not, they are $1/(n-2)$ by the induction hypothesis. (I accidentally omitted the reciprocal in my above comment.)

Comment: Sorry, I think I poorly stated my last comment. I meant to say that for every $Q(n_1,n_2) = \frac{1}{n_1+n_2-1}$. So yes, I agree that the $Q$ terms are $\frac{1}{n-2}$ since: $$Q(n_1-1,n_2)=\frac{1}{(n_1-1+n_2)-1} = \frac{1}{n_1+n_2-2} = \frac{1}{n-2} = Q(n_1,n_2-1)$$. However I still don't understand how the induction hypothesis implies that $Q(n_1,n_2) = \frac{1}{n_1+n_2-1}$ for every $n_1$ and $n_2$. Apologies for my slowness, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @lstbl: I'm sorry if my comments haven't been helpful; I'm afraid I don't understand well enough where you're stuck. We seem to agree that the two $Q$ terms on the right-hand side are $1/(n-2)$. If you substitute that into the recurrence, you have two terms that both contain a factor $1/((n-1)(n-2))$, and factoring that out yields $((n_1-1)+(n_2-1))/((n-1)(n-2))$. The numerator is $n-2$, so you can cancel the factors of $n-2$, leaving $1/(n-1)$. I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42941/discussion-between-lstbl-and-joriki).